# What was the episode of a 90s cartoon where an enemy of Batman was fixated on time?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman, tv, cartoon

I'm looking for the episode and enemy name from a Batman cartoon from probably the '90s.  The enemy is a skinny nerdy character with a cane for a weapon, his glasses have a clock face on them and he knows the speed of Batman's punches and kicks and so can dodge them.  He's very fixated on 'time'.

Comment: http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/The_Clock_King, http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Out_of_Joint, http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_Fugate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are definitely looking for [The Clock King](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/The_Clock_King) episode from *Batman: The Animated Series*.

> **The enemy is a skinny nerdy character with a cane for a weapon,**

Yup. Bonus: it's the hand of a clock.

[image: cane. check]

> **his glasses have a clock face on them**

This matches.

[image]

> **and he knows the speed of batmans punches and kicks and so can dodge them.**

This is accurate. He has studied Batman in-depth and attempts to use the statistics against Batman.

> Fugate: I've studied news footage of you, and I know that it takes you exactly a twentieth of a second to throw a punch.
>   Batman: Very clever. But it only takes me a thirtieth of a second......to do this! (Throws a kick at Fugate)

> **He's very fixated on 'time'.**

Temple Fugate starts out as a nerdy time-obsessed lawyer. When a co-worker suggests he relaxes a bit, he ends up being late for a court appearance, and loses his case and eventually career. He blames his co-worker for his ruin and becomes a criminal bent on revenge.

Comment: ninj'd on building the answer :( - at least my comment shows I was "first" :D

Comment: Your answer is much more detailed and accurate than mine, so removed mine to make way. :)